# How Can I Set-up AdBrite on a Flex 3 Website Using iFrames

Tags: apache-flex, iframe

I'd like to set-up AdBrite on my Flex 3 website. AdBrite suggested that I use an iFrame. I've never used an iFrame before. Any advice on how to set it up?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

UPDATE
Flextras.com was kind enough to post some links. (I did Google it prior to posting). I plan to use the flex-iframe found at: http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/. But, I'm not sure how to adapt this sample code to work with AdBrite:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                xmlns:flexiframe="http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/">

              <flexiframe:IFrame id="googleIFrame"
                            label="Google"
                            source="http://www.google.com"
                            width="80%"
                            height="80%"/>
<mx:Application>
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Thank you.

-Laxmidi

UPDATE:

Please find below the ad code. I need to figure out how to use this in an iFrame:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var AdBrite_Title_Color = 'FFFFFF';
var AdBrite_Text_Color = '000000';
var AdBrite_Background_Color = '8C9DD1';
var AdBrite_Border_Color = 'CCCCCC';
var AdBrite_URL_Color = '008000';
try{var AdBrite_Iframe=window.top!=window.self?2:1;var AdBrite_Referrer=document.referrer==''?document.location:document.referrer;AdBrite_Referrer=encodeURIComponent(AdBrite_Referrer);}catch(e){var AdBrite_Iframe='';var AdBrite_Referrer='';}
</script>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,83,67,82,73,80,84));document.write(' src="http://ads.adbrite.com/mb/text_group.php?sid=2345566&zs=2222385f3630&ifr='+AdBrite_Iframe+'&ref='+AdBrite_Referrer+'" type="text/javascript">');document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,47,83,67,82,73,80,84,62));</script>
<a target="_top" href="http://www.adbrite.com/mb/commerce/purchase_form.php?opid=2345566&afsid=1"><img src="http://files.adbrite.com/mb/images/adbrite-your-ad-here-banner.gif" style="background-color:#CCCCCC;border:none;padding:0;margin:0;" alt="Your Ad Here" width="11" height="60" border="0" /></a></span>
```

Thank you for your posts.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you Google [Flex iFrame](http://www.google.com/search?q=Flex+iFrame&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).  It comes up with some useful links:

http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/

http://www.themidnightcoders.com/blog/2006/12/mixing-html-and-flex-using-iframe.html

http://www.ohloh.net/p/flex-iframe

Drumbeat Insight also has an [HTML Component](http://drumbeatinsight.com/htmlcomponent) for Flex which uses the iFrame trick.

Update:

The original poster posted code, so this update is in relation to that.  To use iFrame with adBrite, just specify a URL to an HTML Page with adBrite information in it by changing the source:

Given the user's code:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                xmlns:flexiframe="http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/">

              <flexiframe:IFrame id="googleIFrame"
                            label="Google"
                            source="http://www.mysite.com/adBright.html"
                            width="80%"
                            height="80%"/>
<mx:Application>
```

Comment: Hi Flextras.com, Thank you for the message. I did Google it. I've been looking at the code on http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/. I haven't figure out yet, how to use AdBrite with it. I'll update my question with more detail in a second. -Laxmidi

Comment: Thnak you for the update. I've got the ad snippet. Any suggestions on how to get this to work in an iFrame? Thank you for your posts.

Comment: Thanks www.flextras.com. It was straight forward. I put the adBrite code in an HTML file. and then pointed the IFrame to it.